# How to check and wait previous file is completed and execute next files

Tags: python, linux

system: Linux, Ubuntu

I have several files needs to execute sequentially (to execute command iperf), I created a main.py file and imports these files,
after all iperf done, need to reset setting (file: reset.py).
And one of the file in these files need to run from start and end before reset.py (to get cpu log), so I use background execution, the code below:

```
r = os.system('python3 getcpu.py &)
print(r)
```

The question is, I try to control timer (ex: time.sleep() or threading..etc.) cannot make reset.py run after getcpu.py,
how could I check the file getcpu.py is completed and then run next file(reset.py)?

I draw the structure below:

[image]

===== update code and description below =====

Bbecause the full code a little bit long, I paste key point here.
I need to get cpu log when run all iperf commands, I use the background work method, so that the program can be executed synchronously.

```
from Modules.ConfigModule import *        # preset settings


def get_cpu():   # background execution

 r = os.system('python3 getcpu.py &') 
 print(r)

get_cpu()

from Iperf1 import *

from Iperf2 import *

from Iperf3 import *

from Iperf4 import *

from Modules.resetModule import *
```

the file getcpu.py command below:

```
# SSH connection
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('mpstat -P ALL 1400')
info = stdout.readlines()
print(info)
# I set 1400 sec. because I want to make sure get complete cpu report
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for not clearly, the code was updated above content.

Comment: I see now what you want to do. Perhaps a library like https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html or https://pypi.org/project/psutil/ or https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html does what you want? I believe there are better ways than to manually check the mpstat yourself. You can run those in a separate thread.

Comment: Many thanks for provide these three modules, I will try. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can try using `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.system()`.
It blocks the execution until the process finishes.</s>

```py
import subprocess

r = subprocess.run(['python3', 'getcpu.py'])

print(r.returncode)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Based on new information you can write a profiler yourself with the psutil package and threading like so:

```py
import psutil
from threading import Thread
import time

class Profiler:
  def __init__(self):
    self.stop = False
    self.thread = Thread(target=self.do_profile)

  def profile_start(self):
    self.thread = Thread(target=self.do_profile)
    self.thread.start()

  def profile_stop(self):
    self.stop = True
    self.thread.join()

  def do_profile(self):
    while not self.stop:
      print(psutil.cpu_percent())
      time.sleep(0.1) #delay between cpu collections
    self.stop = False


p = Profiler()

p.profile_start()

print("Importing Module 1")
from pandas import *

print("Importing Module 2")
from PySide2 import *

print("Importing Module 3")
from matplotlib import *

p.profile_stop()
```

This prints

```
Importing Module 1
0.0
23.2
40.4
14.3
32.1
10.7
12.5
7.1
10.5
14.0
7.1
14.3
7.0
26.3
14.0
8.9
Importing Module 2
7.0
26.8
7.1
16.3
17.2
10.7
18.8
17.9
21.4
14.3
17.9
21.4
0.0
5.4
10.7
12.5
10.7
22.8
10.7
8.9
22.8
Importing Module 3
10.5
21.1
```

Of course, you can edit the `do_profile` function to format the output however you like. I chose to get the CPU percentage. But there are also other stats.
Take a look here: https://pypi.org/project/psutil/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just tried but this method is not applicable for my case, because I need to get complete cpu report for ALL iperf commends/files, so I set getcpu.py backround work for executed synchronously.

Comment: I edited my answer, is this more what you wanted?

Comment: Amost!! I got a new way to write a code. Many thanks! :)